# How to change the size of small wizard image and have custom fields in inno setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want all my inno set up pages to look like below :

[image: customer license page]

[image: options page]

Comment: Sorry, but from the screenshots as they are and from the question *How to change the size of small wizard image*; did you mean how to replace the original main panel (the top one) with your custom image (or another control) with labels over it (or simply modify it to looks the same as on the screenshots) ? About the custom fields you need to use the custom pages as you already know but it's out of scope of this question if you asked for the top panel modificaton (even if I'll try to include a sample of it).

Comment: Yes TLama,i wan't to replace the top panel image with my own image...as i googled and read the inno setup documents,the size of this image is fixed...i want to reposition and replace this image with my own image...also if i can change the font of the page title and reposition it ,it would be great..Sorry but i should have been more precise in my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The small wizard image is accessible using [`WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm) which is of type [`TBitmapImage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TBitmapImage).
You can change the size and position of this control to suit your design (within the top panel). You can also hide/reposition the labels (`WizardForm.PageNameLabel` and `WizardForm.PageDescriptiontLabel`) in the same way.

As for the extra fields, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068544/how-can-i-create-my-own-form-or-page-an-inno-setup-based-installer).

Comment: Thanks Deanna..Is there a property to reposition/change font of  the page header,Lisensvalidering in above image(1)..

Comment: You can learn how to customize the pages by yourself. First you need to see the [`classes reference`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm) where is the list of all available classes and their properties used in the whole wizard. Then you need to find what component is the label you need to change (what is not always so easy, but if you have Delphi, you can open the form at its design time) find the proper reference in the classes list and write the code.

Comment: Here for instance there are two labels on the main panel, the `PageNameLabel` and `PageDescriptionLabel`. If you search for them in the classes reference, you will see they are of the type of `TNewStaticText` which has `Font` property. So as first you will hide the `PageDescriptionLabel` and then change the `Font` properties like you wish, but this is out of the scope of this question. Anyway, you can also upvote (like I did here) the answers by the arrow at the accept check box, it will increase our motivation ;-)