# How to remove the bottom panel in inno set up..and replace it with a custom panel

Tags: installation, inno-setup

i want to replace the bottom panel where we show Next,Back buttons with a custom panel which includes the installation progress bar..once the installation is completed,then page should automatically redirected to next page.
Below is mockup image,how i want to make this page.

[image]

Comment: Or you can build your own InnoSetup, it's open source written in Delphi. I haven't said it's not possible in script code, but just easier would be to modify the InnoSetup itself.

Comment: thanks TLama, where can i get the source code for InnoSetUp...anyways.it would have been better if i could have managed this through the script it self.

Comment: InnoSetup source you can download [`from here`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/download.php/issrc.zip). About the script, you need to consider it might be quite long since you will move, resize and hide a lot of components, I'll make an exception and help you with it, but the best is to try it by your own ;-)

Comment: While it's possible to change the panels, Inno is very tightly tied to the standard wizard flow and so requires stuff to be done when it expects. Trying to do the install (presumably what the progress bar is for) outside this is going to be a PITA.

Comment: @Deanna, it isn't. When you enter the `wpInstalling` page, you'll just stretch the `InnerPage.Notebook` to be client aligned, change the parent for `NextButton`, `BackButton`, `ProgressGauge`, `StatusLabel` and `FilenameLabel` to that `InnerPage.Notebook` and reposition them. After you leave the page change all back as it was (if needed).

Comment: Ah yeah, I was assuming they wanted it below the normal pages for some reason. Answer away :)

Comment: @Deanna, even this is easy to do if you change the parent of the `ProgressGauge` and those two labels to `WizardForm` and *move* them to the bottom when the page is being shown ;-)

Comment: @Sunil, could you specify what exactly you want to achieve ? Do you want that bottom panel (the gray one on your picture) to be visible on all pages (including welcome and finish ones) ? You mentioned buttons though but there are none on your picture. I can modify the script to reflect your needs quite quickly but I need to know precisely when the panel should be shown. With the current script I've posted is only on the install page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the script including also the main panel header from your [`previous question`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11193811/960757) as well. Save it into your `..\InnoSetup\Examples\` folder as well as the following images which you need to convert to BMP files since I couldn't find any trusted file sharing site which wouldn't convert the images to PNG or JPG format:

- [`this one`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK4rN.png) convert to BMP and save as `Logo.bmp`
- [`this one`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddHOv.png) convert to BMP and save as `InstallBackground.bmp`

Here is the script (you should follow the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11218782/1) of this script first):

```
[Setup]
AppName=ERPBO
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output
WizardSmallImageFile=Logo.bmp

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "InstallBackground.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.chm"; Check: JustBlockTheInstallPage

[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Installere - %1
WizardInstalling=Installasjon pågår...

[Code]
function JustBlockTheInstallPage: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;  
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Pakker ut filer...';
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption :='C:\dnpr\Crystal reports setup\WindowShoppingNet.msi';
  MsgBox('Message just to see the install page :-)', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

var
  InnerNotebookBounds: TRect;
  OuterNotebookBounds: TRect;
  InstallBottomPanel: TPanel;
  InstallBackground: TBitmapImage;

function Rect(const ALeft, ATop, ARight, ABottom: Integer): TRect;
begin
  Result.Left := ALeft;
  Result.Top := ATop;
  Result.Bottom := ABottom;
  Result.Right := ARight;
end;

function GetBoundsRect(AControl: TControl): TRect;
begin
  Result.Left := AControl.Left;
  Result.Top := AControl.Top;
  Result.Right := AControl.Left + AControl.Width;
  Result.Bottom := AControl.Top + AControl.Height;
end;

procedure SetBoundsRect(AControl: TControl; const ARect: TRect);
begin
  AControl.Left := ARect.Left;
  AControl.Top := ARect.Top;
  AControl.Width := ARect.Right - ARect.Left
  AControl.Height := ARect.Bottom - ARect.Top;
end;

procedure CenterHorizontally(ASource, ATarget: TControl);
begin
  ATarget.Left := (ASource.Width - ATarget.Width) div 2;
end;

procedure CenterVertically(ASource, ATarget: TControl);
begin
  ATarget.Top := (ASource.Height - ATarget.Height) div 2;  
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin              
  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Visible := False;

  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Font.Size := 18;
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Font.Name := 'Comic Sans MS';
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.AutoSize := True;
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Left := 18;
  CenterVertically(WizardForm.MainPanel, WizardForm.PageNameLabel); 

  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
  WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Left := WizardForm.ClientWidth - WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Width - 18;
  CenterVertically(WizardForm.MainPanel, WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage); 

  WizardForm.InstallingPage.Color := clWhite;  

  InstallBottomPanel := TPanel.Create(WizardForm);
  InstallBottomPanel.Parent := WizardForm.InstallingPage;
  InstallBottomPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  InstallBottomPanel.Align := alBottom;
  InstallBottomPanel.Caption := '';
  InstallBottomPanel.Color := $00C7CFD3;
  InstallBottomPanel.Height := 79;
  InstallBottomPanel.ParentBackground := False;

  ExtractTemporaryFile('InstallBackground.bmp');

  InstallBackground := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  InstallBackground.Parent := WizardForm.InstallingPage;
  InstallBackground.AutoSize := True;
  InstallBackground.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\InstallBackground.bmp'));

  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Parent := InstallBottomPanel;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Left := 8;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Top := 8;
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Parent := InstallBottomPanel;
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Left := 8;
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Top := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Top + 16;
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent := InstallBottomPanel;
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Left := 8;
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Top + 26;

  InnerNotebookBounds := GetBoundsRect(WizardForm.InnerNotebook);
  OuterNotebookBounds := GetBoundsRect(WizardForm.OuterNotebook);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);  
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
    SetBoundsRect(WizardForm.OuterNotebook, Rect(OuterNotebookBounds.Left, 
      OuterNotebookBounds.Top, OuterNotebookBounds.Right, WizardForm.ClientHeight));
    SetBoundsRect(WizardForm.InnerNotebook, Rect(OuterNotebookBounds.Left,
      WizardForm.Bevel1.Top + WizardForm.Bevel1.Height, OuterNotebookBounds.Right, 
      WizardForm.ClientHeight));          

    CenterHorizontally(WizardForm.InstallingPage, InstallBackground);
    InstallBackground.Top := InstallBottomPanel.Top - InstallBackground.Height;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Width := InstallBottomPanel.Width - 16;
  end
  else
  begin
    SetBoundsRect(WizardForm.OuterNotebook, OuterNotebookBounds);
    SetBoundsRect(WizardForm.InnerNotebook, InnerNotebookBounds);
  end;
end;
```

And the result how the installation page looks like (and yes, I have used Comic Sans :-)

[image]

Comment: P.S. I know it doesn't look exactly as on your picture, but that's how I felt it better. And try to take this as an inspiration not as a direct answer to your quite unclear question (since you have asked for a bottom panel with buttons, but on your picture there are no buttons). But the principle would be the same; you'll just change the parent of the buttons to the `InstallBottomPanel` used in this example and stretch the notebooks in different steps. If you were more precise I might do that directly.

Comment: Now looking on it again; if you would like to have buttons on that gray panel and have that panel on every page (including welcome and finish pages), it would be better to create that panel as child of the `OuterNotebook` which would be stretched once and forever in `InitializeWizard`. In the middle white part from your picture would be stretched the `InnerNotebook` which holds all wizard pages...

Comment: I wish I were :-) But anyway, consider my comments here if you need to have that panel on every page. The best you can see the wizard form composition in Delphi from the InnoSetup source's `Wizard.dfm` form. I can't make a complex script for your setup since every screenshot you've posted is somehow *inconsistent*.

Comment: I am trying to use this code to understand how to move down the progressbar. I Only need move down the progress bar. How to do this? Sorry for my bad english.