# Welcome Label Transparent on Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How do I WelcomeLabel on Inno Setup does not appear and leave only the text over the image.

This is that i want.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using [Graphical Installer](http://www.graphical-installer.com/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick. Since the welcome labels don't support transparency, you need to workaround this by creating your own with a different class (that has a transparency support), inherit the parent, font, text and size and hide the original ones. Here is the script how to do this:

```
[Code]
procedure InheritBoundsRect(ASource, ATarget: TControl);
begin
  ATarget.Left := ASource.Left;
  ATarget.Top := ASource.Top;
  ATarget.Width := ASource.Width;
  ATarget.Height := ASource.Height;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  TopWelcomeLabel: TLabel;
  BottomWelcomeLabel: TLabel;
begin
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Align := alClient;
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Image.bmp');

  TopWelcomeLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  TopWelcomeLabel.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Parent;
  TopWelcomeLabel.Font := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Font;
  TopWelcomeLabel.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Caption;
  TopWelcomeLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.WordWrap;
  InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1, TopWelcomeLabel);
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Visible := False;

  BottomWelcomeLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  BottomWelcomeLabel.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Parent;
  BottomWelcomeLabel.Font := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Font;
  BottomWelcomeLabel.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption;
  BottomWelcomeLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.WordWrap;
  InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2, BottomWelcomeLabel);
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Visible := False;
end;
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: This script can be optimized but I need to find out how much you know about InnoSetup Pascal Script or Pascal commonly. But as first I need some feedback from you...

Comment: Looks promising, but still not quite what the OP has shown in their example screenshot. Good effort!

Comment: TLama, Thank you very much. This is exactly what I want to do. My question was answered by 100% for you.

Comment: Hi again TLama, i take your script and make a simple installer but appear a white box behind the text. Please see http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/1207/imagecpd.jpg

Comment: TLama, see as it was. http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4905/image1hnp.jpg. I put on my main script and look this: http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/394/image2jfe.jpg still appear the backgtround on text.

Comment: Make sure you're hiding the original labels (the lines where I've been setting `Visible` to False). If you're doing so, then please include your script into the question and mention also the InnoSetup version you're using and I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi again TLama, i dont know put my code here on the comment, so plese see the link to download. https://rapidshare.com/#!download|508p8|1437426239|Andrezork%20Script.txt|3|0|0

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. From a quick look into your script seems you're using the original labels (`WelcomeLabel1` and `WelcomeLabel2`). If you want to have transparent labels, you need to create your own labels from the `TLabel` class and hide those `WelcomeLabel1` and `WelcomeLabel2`.

Comment: Hi TLama, thank you for your answer. How can i create my own labels? Can you give me a example?

Comment: Exactly the way I've used in my post ;-)

Comment: TLama, hi again. Please see the script. Now the label are transparent, but the progress bar, directory search and the checkbox to the icon on desktop, i don´t know to make a background transparent. If you help me, i will be greatful. https://rapidshare.com/files/2431155186/Teste.iss

Comment: Hi, @Andrezork, sorry, but without proper formatting this would take me a long time (nested `with` statements are really the worst you could use for this kind of a script). But to your questions, progress bar is *naturally transparent* or looks so, see e.g. [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11218782/960757). With check box it's worse since it's not transparent and doesn't support transparency. However you can simulate your check box as transparent if you size it exactly to its box part and for its caption add an extra label. Unfortunately, there won't be a mouse hover for the caption part.

Comment: Hello TLama, thank you again for your help. I will try to make this installer of other way. It´s not very important, i just want make a diferent way to organizar my games in my PC. Thank you again for your atention and help. Best regards.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but on Windows Server 2008 I had to set TopWelcomeLabel.Transparent:=True (on Win10 it worked without setting this).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you want may not be possible or rather difficult, even if creating a custom page. Have a look at the [CreateCustomPage()](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustompage) function and the example scripts included with your Inno Setup installation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I donnt understanding a lot of the script,if you have any example to show me, i will be gratful.

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you. Just change the Welcome page, but you can try with other pages of the installer.

```
[code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

function GetCustomSetupExitCode(): Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  WLabel1, WLabel2,
  FLabel1, FLabel2: TLabel;
begin
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Hide;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Hide;
  WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Hide;
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Hide;
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Width := 500;
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Height := 315;

  WLabel1 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  WLabel1.Left := ScaleX(176); 
  WLabel1.Top := ScaleY(16);
  WLabel1.Width := ScaleX(301); 
  WLabel1.Height := ScaleY(54); 
  WLabel1.AutoSize := False;
  WLabel1.WordWrap := True;
  WLabel1.Font.Name := 'verdana'; 
  WLabel1.Font.Size := 12; 
  WLabel1.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  WLabel1.Font.Color:= clBlack; 
  WLabel1.ShowAccelChar := False;
  WLabel1.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Caption;
  WLabel1.Transparent := True;
  WLabel1.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;

  WLabel2 :=TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  WLabel2.Top := ScaleY(76);
  WLabel2.Left := ScaleX(176); 
  WLabel2.Width := ScaleX(301); 
  WLabel2.Height := ScaleY(234); 
  WLabel2.AutoSize := False;
  WLabel2.WordWrap := True;
  WLabel2.Font.Name := 'tahoma'; 
  WLabel2.Font.Color:= clBlack; 
  WLabel2.ShowAccelChar := False;
  WLabel2.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption;
  WLabel2.Transparent := True;
  WLabel2.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;

  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Width := 500; 
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Height := 315; 

  FLabel1 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm); 
  FLabel1.Left := ScaleX(176); 
  FLabel1.Top := ScaleY(16);
  FLabel1.Width := ScaleX(301); 
  FLabel1.Height := ScaleY(54); 
  FLabel1.AutoSize := False;
  FLabel1.WordWrap := True;
  FLabel1.Font.Name := 'verdana'; 
  FLabel1.Font.Size := 12; 
  FLabel1.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  FLabel1.Font.Color:= clBlack; 
  FLabel1.ShowAccelChar := False;
  FLabel1.Caption := WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Caption;
  FLabel1.Transparent := True;
  FLabel1.Parent := WizardForm.FinishedPage;

  FLabel2 :=TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  FLabel2.Top := ScaleY(76);
  FLabel2.Left := ScaleX(176); 
  FLabel2.Width := ScaleX(301); 
  FLabel2.Height := ScaleY(53); 
  FLabel2.AutoSize := False;
  FLabel2.WordWrap := True;
  FLabel2.Font.Name := 'tahoma'; 
  FLabel2.Font.Color:= clBlack; 
  FLabel2.ShowAccelChar := False;
  FLabel2.Caption := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption;
  FLabel2.Transparent := True;
  FLabel2.Parent := WizardForm.FinishedPage;
end;
```