# Inno Setup: How to have transparent color text in this Welcome window script

Tags: colors, inno-setup, transparent

I need to know how have white (or other) color text in this script. Really I need make the Welcome screen with full background image, text in color and one image in left bottom window.

```
[Files]
DestName: "WizardForm.BitmapImage1.bmp"; Source: "embedded\Alfreire.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy solidbreak

[Code]
{ RedesignWizardFormBegin } // Don't remove this line!
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
var
  BitmapImage1: TBitmapImage;

procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
  with WizardForm do
  begin
    Caption := '{#AppName}... by -=4lfre1re=-';
    Color := clWhite;
  end;

  { BitmapImage1 }
  BitmapImage1 := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  with BitmapImage1 do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(314);
    Width := ScaleX(250);
    Height := ScaleY(46);
    ExtractTemporaryFile('WizardForm.BitmapImage1.bmp');
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\WizardForm.BitmapImage1.bmp'));
  end;

  with WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage do
  begin
    Width := ScaleX(497);
  end;

  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2 do
  begin
    Transparent := True;
    Top := ScaleY(98);
  end;

  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1 do
  begin
    Font.Height := -21;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Transparent := True;
    Height := ScaleY(79);
  end;

{ ReservationBegin }
  // This part is for you. Add your specialized code here.

{ ReservationEnd }
end;
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
{ RedesignWizardFormEnd } // Don't remove this line!

procedure WizardFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  RedesignWizardForm;
end;
```

[image: welcome screen image]

Comment: VirtualBox already has installer. There's no need for repack.

Comment: `Font.Color := clWhite;`

Comment: Where I put that in script...?  Virtualbox it's only a example, i want this for all my installers... I searched solution in answers, but not found solution in them... Thanks and regards... ;-9

Comment: Difficult to say. Your script is autogenerated somehow (or at least comments inside claim that). You will probably need to add it after `RedesignWizardForm` call (e.g. `WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Font.Color := clWhite;`).

Comment: @TLama I will try... Yes, script is genetarted by Inno Setup Ultra / WizardForm designer... Apologies for not doing everything correctly in my first post... thanks and regards... ;-)

Comment: No worries ;-) But wait, now I remember, welcome labels cannot be transparent. This question is a [`better duplicate`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11963522/960757).